# Ground my body to DC (USB)

Tags: voltage, usb, dc, grounding

Does grounding body to DC power source makes sense, to get rid of any electrostatic(?) charges from my skin/body ? 
In my new house, when I'm standing on the floor, connect voltage meter (AC) and ground myself to ground pin in AC socket, then it shows ~40 Volts and when sitting on the chair and it goes down to 18 Volts. Current is below 1mA.
I'm simply scared to connect myself to 220V socket (ground) as someone else might put something into it, change wiring, so decided with some lower voltages.
I was wondering about buying "grounding matt", but they are not quickly reachable where I live, so I'm wondering about grounding my body to DC source, like USB port. This way, my voltmeter (when set to AC) goes down to 1 Volt. When I set it to DC, it shows ~0.6V.
So here come my two questions regarding this "grounding", like...
1. Does grounding body to DC (minus in USB socket) makes sense and current does really flow off me ? I may use some diode like 1N4148 if needed.
2. Any other/better solutions for grounding body ? There is too much "marketing" on the network, so I'd like to hear experts comments from you guys.

Comment: 40V / 10Mohm = 4uA

Comment: Do you need a ground 'strap' because you are working on electronic devices? Or is this some else?

Comment: @Sparky256 - let's say it's some kind of an experiment I'm carrying out on myself by grounding myself with use of DC. It's about health and few other factors affecting body. Will tell more later. Right now, I'd like to know the answer for the first question the most, or more precisely, how should such grounding method be carried out. Safely and efficiently.

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all. Can you clarify what you are actually measuring/trying to achieve.

Comment: This is close to being off-topic, and dangerous.

Comment: 'grounding myself with use of DC" You don't ground yourself using a signal. You ground yourself to a physical ground reference, be it the GND net on your motherboard, or the physical dirt in your lawn. Anyway, don't stick yourself to a USB socket. It's neither safe for you nor for your computer.

Comment: This question appears not to be about electrical engineering, but some sort of non-science superstition.  Even the part that is about electronics is so confused that a reasonable answer doesn't fit with this Q&A format.

Comment: @Olin - okay, correcting myself, sorry. So...if I wanted to say I want to get rid of any electrostatic charge from my body and "put" it away from me, would connecting my body to DC USB minus (negative) have any sense and be practical ?

Comment: What you are saying is confused babble at best, non-science nonsense at worst.

Comment: @AlanStaney Or, you could just touch a piece of construction metal in your house or workplace (e.g. door frame, etc) without doing risky nonsense with USB ports and ground prongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grounding mats, properly installed have a large resistor ( think 1000 kohm ) between the mat and earth ground.  The mat may take a static discharge of thousands of volts and the the resistor limits the current as it drains away the static charge.  That high impedance will not quench the AC field picked up by the body.

Grounding to USB will couple the AC field picked up by the body to the USB 5V return.  As the USB DC source is isolated from AC - there may not be a path to drain off the AC field voltage.  The AC will not go away and now the USB port will rise and fall with the picked-up AC field.

You are right to pause before wrapping bare copper around your wrist and plugging it into an outlet.  DO NOT DO IT!

In order to help with the underlying issue that is leading to grounding the body, please state what is that underlying issue.

Comment: I want to get rid of any charge form my skin, AC and DC. I'm not sure I said it right, so correct me if needed, please.

Comment: The question is *why* do you need to do this?

Comment: @AlanStaney You can bring your voltage to ground by touching the case of any metal, grounded appliance (toaster, oven, etc.)  However, to anything not at ground voltage (which itself varies), you would still appear charged.  If your goal is to avoid static with something you're working on, look up standard electronics anti-static techniques.  Lastly, you can't really remove _all_ charge from your skin--consider that an EKG works by measuring the voltage differences on your skin from the action of your heart.

Comment: I don't know why I got some "minus" points here by so many users, with comment like "This question does not appear to be about electronics design within the scope...", when in fact it is about it. I see you misunderstood my question or didn't read it correctly, as they two lead to some request for such "electric design".
Anyway, I've just spoke to some guy here and we'll work on what I wish to achieve.
@scorpdaddy - you wanted to know "why do I need to do this", but your question makes complete no sense here, since this forum is not about "Why you want it", but "how can I help you".

Comment: For others interested, this idea of grounding body came to me some time ago from some bioenergotherapeutic (?) professor I met some time ago, and over the last months, also my Chi master suggested me, that it would be wise for me to, let's say, "follow this path" to reduce pain I face right now (1 out of ~10000). It's a matter of some balance inside body, and the reason I asked about DC was that ions and their movement through human body parts is closer to DC than AC. 
Nevertheless, thank you all for suggestions, and since scorpdaddy also wrote about possible AC "blocking", he gets the point.